# 20.04 - How to debug frequent freezes

Tags: 20.04, macbook

I recently converted my old Macbook pro to 20.04 and the performance is not what I expected. Granted it's on older hardware, it'll still hang on simple tasks for ~15 minutes until it figures itself out.

For the most part everything else works, however the frequent freezes make it almost unusable.

Is there a good way to debug this? I was thinking of downgrading to 18.04.

**Macbook Specs**

8GB RAM/Intel i5 M540

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

GNOME 3.36.8

Comment: I had this on an old PC. Might I suggest that you replace Ubuntu with Lubuntu. It's a bit of a pain to do this, but Lubuntu is designed for slower and older computers, whereas Ubuntu is designed for modern hardware. Be sure to use the official website: https://lubuntu.me/

Comment: @PaddyLandau works much better! thanks for the info

Comment: Good to know. Did you convert to Lubuntu, or did you use a different solution?

Comment: Please let us know what these simple tasks are.